# Most efficient query to increment a few thousand ints in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have about 10k devices, and I want to keep track of their data transfer.

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  transfer INT
);
```

I have been keeping (in memory) a map of the device identifiers and their data transfer since last update. I want to periodically record these increments to my database every minute or so.

At the moment I'm thinking of building a query string (I'm using Go, so `fmt.Sprintf`) to look something like:

```
UPDATE devices SET
    transfer = transfer + temp.transfer
FROM (VALUES
    (1, 500),
    (2, 128),
    (3, 204)  
  ) AS temp(id, transfer) 
WHERE temp.id = devices.id;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Looks ok to me. I expect the plan would use the PK to find the record to update for each record in the VALUES table, so I don't think it would be slow. Presumably there are no other indexes which would get updated when writing to the table.

Comment: As it's an `UPDATE`, and the `transfer` column isn't indexed, there should be no need to recalculate indexes.